# Get field from API on brightspace

Tags: javascript, php, api

I have a function that get all data from the api classlist and show it in json format. However, I want to return only the OrgDefinedId. How could I do that?  Here is my function. I am using JS and php.

```
function getClasslist(){
  hideData();
  document.getElementById("GETField").checked = true;
  document.getElementById("actionField").value = "/d2l/api/bas/1.0/orgunits/167877/classlist/";

}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what is being returned right now?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made it works. The problem in code code was the api. I was using the wrong api.